# Distros that support touchscreen and stylus (on Microsoft Surface Book 2)?

Tags: linux-mint, laptop, distributions, touch-screen, surface

I just installed Mint Cinnamon on my Book 2 laptop, but the OS doesn't seem to recognize/support the touchscreen nor stylus, despite some sources claiming so. If you also have a Surface Book, could you tell me some distros that work for you? Alternatively, in case you don't use Microsoft laptops, could you advise me on the places to ask this kind of question?

Comment: Please give Fedora 38 a try. Updating the kernel to the latest version would be nice.